# AppEngine Search API on development server

Tags: google-app-engine

The problem is really strange. I index some documents on my local development server. The indexes are visible in the admin console (Text Search link). Then i restart the server with the `--clear_datastore` switch. All the datastore entities are gone but when I click on Text Search link in the Admin Console i still see the text search indexes.

How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another flag, `--clear_search_index`, that should clear them

Comment: Thank you! This flag is not documented on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver